# Yii show image in CDetailView

Tags: php, yii, cdetailview

I have stored image in Images Folder(root) In my Yii project. I want to show image in CDetailView that is in protected/view/college

my code

```
array(
            'label'=>'CollegeLogo',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>CHtml::image("../".Yii::app()->baseUrl."/Images/".$model->CollegeLogo),

        ),
```

it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `"../"` in your code. Baseurl will return path from root folder.

```
'value'=>CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/Images/".$model->CollegeLogo),
```

Comment: image is there in folder but it is not showing image url is - <img alt="" src="/LearningYii/CollegeLogo/3150ajax.gif">

Comment: what is the image url and what is the url you are seeing in html source? Post both url in question

Comment: image is there in CollegeLogo Folder under LearnigYii as root folder fullpath is C:\wamp\www\LearningYii\CollegeImages\imagename.jpg

Comment: try the type in `html` like  this `'type'=>'html',`

Comment: in image path there is no `Images` folder. But you are giving in your code.

Comment: That is not problem i have written 'image' to easily understand question i have writter CollegeLogo in my code, it is perfect

Comment: what is the folder name CollegeLogo or CollegeImages?

Comment: That is not problem i have written 'image' to easily understand question i have writter CollegeLogo in my code, it is perfect

Comment: did you try @saravankg suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(

    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'title',
        'date',
        'description',
         array(
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value'=>CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/upload/".$model->image,'alt',array("width"=>"50px" ,"height"=>"50px"))
            ),
        'time',
        'user_id',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
'value'=>CHtml::image(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) . '/Images/'.$model->CollegeLogo),
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the [string format](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDetailView#attributes-detail) `"Name:Type:Label"` with the [Image Type](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter#formatImage-detail)

```
<?php
'attributes' => array(
  "CollegeLogo:image",
  //...
),
```

If the `CollegeLogo` attribute doesn't return the absolute url, I would create a [virtual attribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#defining-and-using-a-component-property) in the model that returns it:

```
public function getCollegeLogoUrl() {
    return "../".Yii::app()->baseUrl."/Images/".$model->CollegeLogo;
}
```

And then use it in the widget:

```
<?php
'attributes' => array(
  "collegeLogoUrl:image",
  //...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

```
array(
            'label'=>'CollegeLogo',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>CHtml::tag('img',
                array("title"=>"CollegeLogo",
                "src"=>Yii::app()->baseUrl."/CollegeImages/".$model->CollegeLogo,
                "style"=>"height:70px")
            )
        ),
```